# Ao minimizar tela grid Bootstrap não quebra para uma nova linha

Tags: html, css, front-end, bootstrap-4

Bom dia, pessoal!

estou com dificuldade de quando o usuario minimizar a tela, os campos antes de sobrepor dentro da grid,
quebrar em uma nova linha....

ps: esse espacamento entre os campos é pra ter msm...

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço a força!

```
 <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row form-group">

        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right;">
            <label for="codigo">Codigo: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" id="codigo" nbInput  />
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right;">
            <label for="ponto">Ponto: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="ponto" id="ponto" nbInput  />
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: camopos sem minimizar:]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou remover essa classe da Row `form-group`?

Comment: oi hugocsl.. obrigado pela forca! tentei sim! quando vou minimizando ele sobrepoe... só queria que antes de sobrepor ele ja fosse pra linha de baixo :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara o que acontece é que o `input` precisa ter um tamanho definido, ou então ele vai assumir algum `width` do *usar-agent* etc. Então como vc quer que ele não quebre o *grid* é só colocar a classe `w-100` no `input`, assim ele nunca será maior que o próprio pai e não vai encobrir os elementos ao lado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código do exemplo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  
</style>
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      col-md-4
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right;">
            <label for="codigo">Codigo: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input class="w-100" type="text" id="codigo" nbInput  />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: right;">
            <label for="ponto">Ponto: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <input class="w-100" type="ponto" id="ponto" nbInput  />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pow melhorou muito!
quando eu minimizo ainda fica muito pequenos os campos é possível forçar ele jogar na linha de baixo?
Obg!

Comment: @marcao1569 cara ai vc vai ter que usar o Grid com colunas mais largas, tipo col-md-6. De uma testada nisso depois

Comment: vou testar sim! muito obrigado pela ajuda!